# How to read div id

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this HTML code:

```
> <div class="predictions"> <div class = "competition" id = "07675"> <div '>, <div
> class = "competition"> <div class = "hea"> <div class = "competition"
> <div class = "hea '>, <div class =" competition "> <div class ="
> class = "competition" id = "07560"> <div '>,
```

I'm trying to read the tag `id` from the html. I´m using the code below, but it does not work.

```
response.css ('.//div[@class = "predictions"]/div[id] :: attr (id)')
```

[image]

Comment: If you use xpath you mast use response.xpath('.//div[@class = "predictions"]/div[@id]'). In example above you use mix xpath and css style =) It's don't work

Comment: Ops. The work =)

Comment: Ops. The work =)

But i cannot read return data? I try .extract() return all html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a CSS selector with an xpath expression.

If you want to use xpath expression, you should do something like this:

```
response.xpath(xpression)
```

Also, the xpath expression for the element you want is probably this:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="competition"]/@id')
```

This expression will search for any `div` with `class="competition"` and return it's `id` attribute. The HTML you posted is a bit messy so I didn't really test it, but it seems correct. if you have any doubts building your xpath, or want to improve it on your own here is a [great guide](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).